# Change all the user id to Facebook name

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

In my page, there are many hyperlink. i want to change all the 'a' with 'uid' attribute to be like this:

```
<a href=# uid="5526183">5526183</a>
```

to be

```
<a href=# uid="5526183">Afrig Aminuddin</a>
```

another example

```
<a href=# uid="5526183">My name is 5526183</a>
```

to be

```
<a href=# uid="5526183">My name is Afrig Aminuddin</a>
```

First: i'll get all the 'a' tag with 'uid' attribute

```
var uid=$('a[uid]');
```

then i call the function, this function will only be called once page loaded...

```
named(uid);
```

Here is my Function

```
function named(uid){

// here i'd like to do something with the 'uid' array in order it can be 
// processed in the next line

// in the next line, the 'uid' must be unique
// so, before that i'd like to filter all the 'uid' array in order to 
// filter the double 'uid'

 FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (5526183,1000014057,100001491471735)'
  },
  function(response) {
    // change all the 'a' with 'uid' attribute here...

    // response example
    return response[0].name; //return the name of 5526183
    return response[1].name; //return the name of 1000014057
    return response[2].name; //return the name of 100001491471735
  }
);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var uid = $("a[uid]").eq(0).attr("uid");

  FB.api(
  {
      method: 'fql.query',
      query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (' + uid + ')'
  },
  function(response) {
      $("a[uid]").each(function () {
          var $this = $(this);

          $this.text(response[0].name);
      });
  });
});
```

that assumes you want to get it each time, meaning you have different uids for each link, otherwise just fetch the name once

Comment: @ivanov:The function will only be called once after page loaded... if it's called each time, it will take a longer time to complete...

Comment: @ ivanov,could you explain how the above code works, im a noob at this kind of js code.

Comment: the FB.api call inside your function is asynchronous, which mean the response will trigger when it is retirned, in that case you will have to pass reference to the link object not just the uid, so that you update it on actual data retrieval

Comment: ok so you will cal it one time, I will edit so it works as described

Comment: basically, when document ready, get the uid, call FB, on response update all links, that assumes u have the correct rights to execute the query on FB and you get return

Comment: @ivanov:thank's for clear explanation... btw, would you mind to explain .geq(0)

Comment: sry, was typo, changed to eq(0), means take first in the collection, since all the same